# POST in AFNetworking with Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i had this piece of code that is used in my app to log in. It used to work in swift 1, but when i brought the whole app to swift it stopped working. NOTE: The code compiles without errors, the problem is that it doesn't execute the request

```
@IBAction func signIn(sender: AnyObject) {
        let body = NetUtils.buildLoginRequestBody(email: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!);
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager();
        manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer() as AFHTTPRequestSerializer;
        manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer();

        barActivityIndicator.startAnimating();
        setViewsEnabled(false);

        manager.POST(LoginURL, parameters: body,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                NSLog("success code: %d", operation.response!.statusCode);
                print(JSON(responseObject))
                self.processUserData(JSON(responseObject));
                self.barActivityIndicator.stopAnimating();
                self.setViewsEnabled(true);

            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, error: NSError!) in
                NSLog("error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                self.barActivityIndicator.stopAnimating();
                self.setViewsEnabled(true);
                self.alert.show();
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Check the link between your `signIn(sender: AnyObject)` and UI Element first

Comment: already checked, its fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by *not executing the request* you mean that the request is failing?

A problem that I see in your code is that you're not holding a reference to your manager, so after the function finishes, it could get deallocated, causing a failure when the closure returns.

If you hold a reference like this:

```
var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

func signIn(sender: AnyObject) { 
    manager.requestSerializer = ...
}
```

Does that work?